# creating an dynamic listview with radiobuttons jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have to create a dynamic listview with radio buttons.

I am able to create the dynamic listview like below

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="storedlist" >
    <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Dynamic listview</h1>
        <a href="#"/></a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="storedList">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my .js file i will append the list element to ul like below

**JS**

```
$('#storedList').append('<li ><a href="#">'+row["nname"]+'</a></li>');
```

The above will get me the dynamic list view.

How will i add the radio buttons to the dynamic listview?.

or is their any other way we can create the dynamic listview with radio button?

Thanks:)

Comment: you want something like this but dynamic? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L2bse/

Comment: @Omar similar one. i will try it. but in the example <form> tag  is not closed know?

Comment: this is a static example only, a teaser. To know what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: @Omar i tried it is working. but list element is displaying like "one" and "two" element of your example. can't i make it to display like "BMW" and "Ferrari" of ur example??

Comment: Check this, it totally dynamic http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L2bse/

Comment: @Omar sorry omar the link you provided above is not what i am trying. please check once. but the link which u gave me first was proper. but the size of element is big i have to make normal like i have said above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30138/discussion-between-omar-and-user2143817)

Answer (score 0):

Work out how you would code the radiobuttons statically, and then use something similar to what you did for each list item to add the radiobuttons dynamically instead.  Since you haven't spelled out details about those buttons, can't go into much more detail than that.  (For example, you'll probably want a button group, and could append your individual buttons into that.)

Comment: i just want text of which radio button is selected. that i can do using ` $('ul').children('li').on('click', function () {
       alert($.trim($(this).text())); });` but i want to display radio button. in static way we need to set <fieldset> then we need to define name, id for each list element and then using the label we will display the listview radio button.. i tried doing that. but i was not able to provide id and name to each list element while creating dynamically.

Comment: I wasn't clear: first figure out (or show us) what the resulting HTML from your desired dynamic code SHOULD look like, and then you/we can figure out how to create it dynamically.